# Заменить все <![CDATA[ и ]]> методом replaceAll без использования регулярных выражений

Tags: java, android, регулярные-выражения

**Дано:**

Есть строка типа

```
<![CDATA[ ТУТ_ТЕКСТ ]]> <![CDATA[ И_ТУТ_ТОЖЕ ]]> <![CDATA[ И_ЕЩЁ ]]>
```

**Задача:**

Надо убрать все встреченные `<![CDATA[` и `]]>` максимально просто. Например, методом `replaceAll()`.

**Пробовал:**

По аналогии с методом `replace` пробовал просто подставить ненужное первым аргументом, но оно не принимается, т.к. ожидает регулярное выражение, а `<![CDATA[` не является валидным выражением.
Пробовал там всё что можно да в разных комбинациях экранировать но успеха не добился.

**Возможное решение:**

Я могу, конечно, пройтись циклом по строке и удалить всё  методом `replace`... Но есть же  метод `replaceAll`...

**Вопрос:**

Как должен выглядеть первый аргумент метода `replacAll` выбирающий `<![CDATA[` и `]]>`? Решение [регулярками](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3212712) не предлагать)

Comment: Так у вас строка или html? если HTML - http://jsoup.org/ А если строка, то регулярки как раз неплохи тут.

Comment: @Vartlok, я JSOUP-ом гружу HTML. В нём есть приведённый текст. Его вот и надо обработать(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так пробовали?

```
System.out.print("<![CDATA[ ТУТ_ТЕКСТ ]]> <![CDATA[ И_ТУТ_ТОЖЕ ]]> <![CDATA[ И_ЕЩЁ ]]>".replaceAll("(<\\!\\[CDATA\\[)|(\\]\\]>)",""));
```

Результат:

```
ТУТ_ТЕКСТ   И_ТУТ_ТОЖЕ   И_ЕЩЁ
```

ЗЫ Для студии есть плагин RegexpTester.
ЗЗЫ Экранирование сделает студия сама, если вставлять регулярку внутрь строки.

Comment: Да, спасибо, так работает) Непонятно только почему экранирующих слэша 2 должно быть..

Comment: Потому что один слэш это экранирование символа в строке. А два слэша - это один экранированный слэш, который передается в регулярку. Стандартная ситуация.

Comment: Понял, спасибо)